# Separar cada CNH e calcular o total dos tempos em condução e parada,

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, lógica

Boa tarde galera... Estou começando com programação e estou com uma duvida em C#.
Primeiramente, preciso separa todas as CNHs para conseguir calcular a soma total de condução de cada motorista. Por exemplo:
CNH: A, ConducaoTotal: 5 horas, ParadaTotal 5 hras.
CNH: B, ConducaoTotal: 2 horas, ParadaTotal 2 hras.
CNH: C, ConducaoTotal: 5 horas, ParadaTotal 5 hras.
Hoje estou tentando passar todos resultados em uma lista, mas acho que dessa forma não vou conseguir separa as CNHs e estou com dificuldade de como posso ajustar isso.

```
       //Criei algumas listas 
        List<string> cnhList = new List<string>();
        List<int> velocidadeList = new List<int>();
        List<DateTime> conducaoTotal = new List<DateTime>();
        List<DateTime> paradaTotal = new List<DateTime>();

       //Estou fazendo dessa forma... passando os resultado dos dados por um foreach e gravando em uma lista para conseguir somar a condução total de um motorista A e motorista B         
        foreach (var response in result.Dados)
        {
            //estou gravando todo resultado dentro de cada variavel e no final salvando em 
            //cada lista.
            string cnh = response.Cnh;
            string hodometro = response.Odometer.ToString();
            int velocidade = response.Velocidad;
            DateTime tempo = response.Time;

           //Aqui estou fazendo uma validação se a velocidade for maior que 10km/h eu gravo 
            //na lista condução total e se for menor grava na parada total.
            if (velocidade > 10)
            {
                DateTime resultTime = time;
                conducaoTotal.Add(time);
            }
            else
            {
                paradaTotal.Add(time);
            }

            cnhList.Add(cnh);
            hodometroList.Add(hodometro);
            velocidadeList.Add(velocidade);

        }
```

Comment: e qual a estrutura do resultado de Dados? pode fazer isso agrupando com linq ou até gerando um dicionário por CNH/soma

Answer (score -2):

Não sei se entendi corretamente, mas acredito que o mais correto seria você criar uma classe, onde teria os dados de CNH, velocidade, parada e condução, por exemplo:

```
public class Viagem
{
    public string CNH {get; set;}
    public int Velocidade {get; set;}
    public DateTime Conducao {get; set;}
    public DateTime Parada {get; set;}
}
```

Dentro do seu foreach, ficaria desta forma:

```
var viagemList = new List<Viagem>();

foreach (var response in result.Dados)
{
    var viagem = new Viagem 
                 {
                    CNH = response.Cnh                
                 };       

    if (response.Velocidad > 10)
        viagem.Conducao = response.Time;
    else            
        viagem.Parada = response.Time;

    viagemList.Add(viagem);
}
```

Entendo que seja isso que procura, porém sua pergunta não está muito clara para quem vai responder. Caso não seja isso, sugiro que revise a pergunta, idente o código, dê espaços nos parágrafos, etc. Tudo isso auxilia para que sua dúvida seja respondida.

Comment: Qual o motivo de negativarem está resposta?